# regexp.test() returns boolean but not on 'if' statement - always evaluates to

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a standalone interface.

I have several text boxes, and all have Names and IDs.

If I run this code:

```
var re = /someregexp/g;
var k ="sometext";

textBoxOne.setText(re.test(k)); //textBoxOne was selected first
```

The correct result 'true' or 'false' is displayed. 
asking for a 'typeof(re.test(k))' correctly returns boolean. 
However this code:

```
if (re.test(k)) {
  textBoxTwo.setText("matched.");
} else {
  textBoxTwo.setText("NOT matched.");
}
```

Always goes into the 'else' branch. if (re.test(k) == true) renders the same result.

Looks like a bug to me, anyone else also found this?

Comment: As per my comment on the post by +David Tew, have you already invoked `re.test(k)` earlier in the script? Because the next invocation will advance past the previous match (and therefore probably not find a match as you might expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: AdamL has pointed out (thanks Adam), in his comments below, that there is more to this than I supposed. I leave my original code below for reference.

The myFunction2() below follows the "matched" branch as you would expect a correctly working regex (so perhaps this can be used to work around the bug):

```
function myFunction2() {
  var k ="sometext";

  Logger.log(  /ome/g.test(k)  ); 
  if ( /ome/g.test(k)  ) {
    Logger.log("matched.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("NOT matched.");
  }
}
```

Conversely, as you have observed, the myFunction() below unexpectedly follows through to the "NOT matched" branch.

```
function myFunction() {
  var re = /ome/g;
  var k ="sometext";

  Logger.log(re.test(k));

  if (re.test(k)) {
    Logger.log("matched.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("NOT matched.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this applies to the OP's post David, but I think it applies to your myFunction(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test "...test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match". So commenting out the Logger.log line will actually make the if() evaluate "correctly".